# `npm run` giving permission denied

Tags: node.js, laravel, ubuntu, npm, laravel-mix

I've started facing an issue today which was not occurring before and no code has been changed on my end.

I'm using Laravel 8 with Laravel Mix and when I run `npm run prod` I keep getting the following:

```
> prod
> npm run production


> production
> mix --production

/tmp/production65665869399.sh: 2: mix: Permission denied
```

Do you have any idea?
I even tried making /tmp directory to have 777 permission and tried to change the owner to be the user I'm logged in as but still the same issue.
It's started all of a sudden and there is no resource about it in the internet.

I'm using Node version 14.15.0 and npm version 8.13.2

This error doesn't occur on my local environment but on AWS Ubuntu server.

Comment: Try run: sudo npm run production

Comment: I tried with sudo and I get the following:
`sudo: npm: command not found`

Comment: I have the same problem. Node works fine in one directory but not in another. My node_modules and /tmp are on different file systems in the case where it breaks (and the same file system in the case where it works). Not sure if that’s related.

Answer (score 1):

Tried to uninstall your node js, and just reinstall it using NVM. Make sure you are not running as root user while installing, hopefully this link can help you:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error

> sh: line 1: /home/ec2-user/smart-ride-backend/node_modules/.bin/nodemon: Permission denied

remove node_modules if using Linux

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

reinstall using

```
npm install
```